# Convert DateTime from mongodb to LocalDate

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have a date save in mongo:

```
    "lastUpdate":{
     "date":"2014-12-04T16:41:31.394+0100"
  },
```

And I would like convert to LocalDate, I have tryed a converter like that:

```
@ReadingConverter
public class DateToLocalDateConverter implements Converter<DateTime, LocalDate> {



@Override
public LocalDate convert(DateTime source) {
    log.debug("inside");
    return new DateTime();
 }
}
```

But I  haven't managed it works. 
Anybody can help me?

thank you

Comment: Not sure to exactly understand your question, but this code : `(new DateTime("2014-12-04T16:41:31.394+0100"))->format("Y-m-d h:i:s")` (in php5.6) will return `2014-12-04 04:41:31`

Comment: I resolved the problem. I received a DBOject instead of DateTime, and after that I convert the dbOject in a LocalDate